# dividing row with a vector in R

Tags: r

lets say I have this data frame
[image]

what I want to do is divide the numbers in the columns by the total number in the last row of each column, I can not, I thought I would do it like this but I get the following error: undefined columns selected.

```
df[4] %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ . / total)
```

In the data i am working on I have 454 columns so specifying them all would be impossible.

Comment: Show us a sample of your original data, with more rows, columns, and totals.

Comment: hi, ofcourse, I will edit the page as it will not let me put a screenshot in here

Comment: Preferably by posting the output of `dput(your_df)` into your question, avoid screenshots.

Comment: Oh im sorry, its too big for dput though dimensions are 17203 / 454

Comment: The whole point of 'dplyr' and related packages is to work on *tidy data*, which has a [specific meaning](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html). Your data isn't tidy by that definition, so using these tools won't work well. The solution in your case is straightforward: as Maurits said, don't include marginal data in your bulk data table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise against including margin totals in raw data. As you found out, it makes things unnecessarily complicated.

That aside, here is an option

```r
df %>%
    mutate(across(b:c, ~ replace(.x, a != "total", .x[a != "total"] / last(.x))))
#      a         b    c
#1    1a 0.4285714 0.25
#2    2a 0.8571429 0.50
#3    3a 0.4285714 0.75
#4 total 7.0000000 8.00
```

This assumes that totals are always in the last row (i.e. the total is the last entry in a column vector).

You can replace `across(b:c, ...)` with `across(where(is.numeric), ...)` if preferable.

---

### Sample data

```r
df <-read.table(text = " a     b     c    
1 1a    3     2 
2 2a    6     4 
3 3a    3     6  
4 total 7     8", header = T)
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. What would be the preffered way to do things like this?

Comment: Keep raw data "raw", i.e. without margin totals. Then transform to calculate quantities (e.g. relative quantities rather than absolute values) as required to generate output tables. There is no need to store totals in raw data as they are trivially calculated.

Comment: PS. That aside, I don't understand why the total in your table is not actually the sum of the other values in column a. I assume this is because this is some simplified sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
df %>% mutate(across(b:c, ~ case_when(a != 'total' ~ ./.[a=='total'],
                                       TRUE ~ .)))
      a         b    c
1    1a 0.4285714 0.25
2    2a 0.8571429 0.50
3    3a 0.2857143 0.75
4 total 7.0000000 8.00
```

Comment: no, I get the following error:
'x' must be size 17203 or 1, not 0.

Comment: @szmple, have updated the code, misunderstood the question initially, can you please check if the updated code works